# python IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, ipython, python-3.7

I am trying neural network feed forward in my anaconda using python3.7 under ipython script.

I'm not familiar and still learning the problem with python and don't know how to debug this.

```
import numpy as np
w1 = np.array([[11, 11, 9, 11, 7,13, 14, 6, 6, 12], [11, 11, 9, 11, 7,13, 14, 6, 6, 12], [11, 11, 9, 11, 7,13, 14, 6, 6, 12]])
w2 = np.zeros ((1,10))
b1 = np.array([0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8, 0.8])
b2 = np.array([0.2])
def f(x):
        return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
def simple_looped_nn_calc(n_layers, x,w,b):
  for l in range(n_layers-1):
    if l == 0:
         node_in = x
    else:
         node_in = h
    h = np.zeros((w[l].shape[0],))
    for i in range(w[l].shape[0]):
       f_sum = 0
       for j in range(w[l].shape[l]):
            f_sum += w[l][i][j]* node_in[j]
       f_sum += b[l][i]
       h[i] = f(f_sum)
  return h



w = [w1, w2]
b = [b1, b2]
x = [280, 0, 280, 280, 0, 0, 0, 0, 280, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 280, 0]
```

When I run my code I get the error , simple_looped_nn_calc(3, x, w, b) like this:

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3

Comment: It would help to know in which line the error appears!

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you wanted to write:

```py
for j in range(w[l].shape[l]):
```

and not

```py
for j in range(w[l].shape[1]):
```

Hope I helped!

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
for j in range(w[l].shape[l])
```

with

```
for j in range(w[l].shape[0])
```

because you are assigning `node_in = h` , h here is  `h = np.zeros((w[l].shape[0],))` , so if you will do `for i in range(w[l].shape[l])` then size of `node_in` and  `w[l].shape[l]` may not match and will cause index errors.

Comment: thank you for your help. May you help me I am trying to make 10 inputs with 10 weights, should I make 10 bias and 10 hidden layer? I need your suggestion.

Comment: what is your expected output ? here in code, bias layers = 'n_layers' ?  and hidden layers = 'h' ?

Comment: sir, my planning is I have input is matrix 19x10 maybe as x value, and weight with matrix 10x1 and expected output is 1.Above is an exercise and for my understanding. Need your suggestion what is the best for bias layer and hidden layers?

Comment: In my suggestion, 1 bias node per input layer and for hidden layers you can hit and try 1,2,...10 which gives you better results. Hidden layers should be in between your input and output layer. You can look this explanation for better understanding of how to select hidden layers https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181/how-to-choose-the-number-of-hidden-layers-and-nodes-in-a-feedforward-neural-netw